# Combine multiple tables into one archive file

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a series of tables that all have the exact same data structures. There is one for each day. Example:

> History 120115
>   History 120215
>   History 120315
>   History 120415
>   ...

I want to combine all of these into one **archival** table for the month.
What's the easiest way to do this month over month?

**Note:** there will be one data table for every day of the month. My goal is to do a monthly, quarterly, and annual "archive".

I'm a novice SQL user, utilizing Access 2016.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This may help to guide you: http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1199984-equivelent-to-SQL-Servers-INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Comment: Instead of a separate table for each date, have you considered a single table with a date column?  The archive task should be less challenging with that design.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, we're forced to import the data into separate tables, otherwise that's exactly what I would consider doing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the archive table, add a field of Date named, say, *HistoryDate* in addition to the existing table schema.

Now, when appending the daily table, fill *HistoryDate* with the date of the source table. It can be retrieved from the table name:

```
Dim t As String
Dim d As Long

t = "History 120315"
d = Val(Split(t, " ")(1))
HistoryDate = DateSerial(d Mod 100, d \ 10000, d \ 100 Mod 100)

' HistoryDate -> 2015-12-03
```

Comment: Great - thanks. Done! Now... how do I combine all the separate tables into one?

Comment: Create a loop that lists the TableDef objects. Filter on those starting with `History `. When one is found, extract the _HistoryDate_ as shown and execute a query that appends the records from the current table to the archive table. Then loop on. You may need to somehow log which tables have been appended to avoid appending them again.